# Python: access variable from string

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to access variables from strings.

Like this:

```
A1 = {}
B1 = {}
C1 = {}

mylist = ["A","B","C"]

for blurb in mylist:
    blurb1.foo()
```

Right now I'm using `if`/`elif` constructions in such cases:

```
if blurb == "A":
    A1.foo()
elif blurb == "B":
    B1.foo()
elif blurb == "C":
    C1.foo()
```

That works, but surely there's a more elegant way of doing it?

**I would like to create and access objects from strings.**

So if I have a function that returns a string, I want to create e.g. a list using this string as the list name, and then do stuff with that list.

```
x = foo() # foo returns a string, e.g. "A"
# create list named whatever the value of x is
# in this case: 
A = []
```

Isn't there anything more elegant than preparing lists for all possible outcomes of `x` and using long `elif` constructions or dictionaries? Do I have to use `eval()` in that case? (I'm hesitant to use `eval()`, as it's considered dangerous.)

Comment: no he is looking for a way to run functions/or access variables (like his dicts above) via string conversion (or other types of conversion)

Comment: something like that, yes. How would i do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer to try to answer your revised request, but could you provide a use case _why_ you want to do this.

Answer (score 11):

I think you want something like

```
lookup = {"A": A1, "B": B1, "C": C1}
obj = lookup.get(blurb,None)
if obj:
   obj.foo()
```

This is usually suggested when someone wants to do something with a switch statement (from c/java/etc.)  Note that the lookup.get (instead of just lookup[blurb] handles the case where blurb is something other than one of the values you defined it for... you could also wrap that in a try/except block.

---

Updated answer based on your revised question, which builds on what Joachim Pileborg had said in another answer.

There are probably better/cleaner ways to do this, but if you really want to set/get via strings to manipulate global objects, you can do that.  One way would be:
To create a new object named "myvariable" (or to set "myvariable" to a new value)

```
joe = "myvariable"
globals().update([[joe,"myvalue"]])
```

To get the object "myvariable" is assigned to:

```
globals().get(joe,None)
```

(or as mentioned in another answer, you could use try/except with direct hash instead of using get)

So for later example, you could do something like:

```
for myobject in mylist:
    # add myobject to list called locus
    # e.g. if locus == "A", add to list "A", if locus == "B" add to list B etc.
    obj = globals().get(myobject.locus,None) # get this list object
    if not obj: # if it doesn't exist, create an empty list named myobject.locus
        obj = []
        globals().update([[myobject.locus,obj]]
    obj.append(myobject) #append my object to list called locus
```

Comment: this is messy, adds a lot of extra checks and a whole extra dictionary.... not very effective for lots of data, or different types of required functions... better use `eval()`.

Comment: eval is evil! (most of the time)

Comment: "A whole extra dictionary." Oh no, one whole dictionary! LOL!

Comment: @Foon: This works, thanks, though it was not exactly what I was looking for. Is there no way to create variable names from strings, like from the output of a function?

Answer (score 7):

You could get the module object, and use `getattr` to get variables/functions from a string:

```
import sys

A = {}
B = {}
C = {}

modname = globals()['__name__']
modobj  = sys.modules[modname]

mylist = ["A","B","C"]

for name in mylist:
    print '%s : %r' % (name, getattr(modobj, name))
```

The above program will print:

```
A : {}
B : {}
C : {}
```

However, it has nothing to do with "wildcards" that you reference in your question, but you don't show any searching for "wildcards".

Comment: I wasn't sure how to call it. I guess "access variable from string" would have been better?

Answer (score 2):

use `eval()`.

example:

```
A1 = []
B1 = []
C1 = []

mylist = ["A","B","C"]

for blurb in mylist:
    eval("%s1.append(blurb)" % blurb)

print A1,B1,C1
>>> 
['A'] ['B'] ['C']
```

and for your code it can be:

```
for blurb in mylist:
    eval("%s1.foo()" % blurb)
```

Comment: Please definitely do not do this.

Comment: @Iguananaut Yeah, i should probably have added some disclaimer that this is a horrible solution. Feel free to edit my answer and add some warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you simply want a dictionary and to look it up rather than run a bunch of checks.

```
dict_look_up = {'A' : A1, 'B' : B1, 'C' : C1}
try:
    dict_look_up[blurb].foo()
except KeyError:
    #whatever on item not found
```

`try/except` blocks are incredibly important in Python (better to ask for forgiveness than permission), so if you're learning I recommend using them from the get go.