# Dynamically define functions with varying signature

Tags: python, dynamic

What I want to accomplish:

```
dct = {'foo':0, 'bar':1, 'baz':2}
def func(**dct):
    pass
#function signature is now func(foo=0, bar=1, baz=2)
```

However, the ** syntax is obviously clashing here between expanding a dict (what I want to do) and declaring a parameter that holds the keyword arguments (what I don't want to do).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my interpretation of your requirements -- you want to dynamically define a function with a signature that matches the content of a`dict` provided at runtime -- there are two issues here which makes it impractical.

1. If the arguments are defined at run-time, how can your function reference the variables? Are you planning to build the function body at run-time as well?
2. `dict`s are unordered, so you cannot reliably use them to define positional arguments

I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you can explain what you're trying to achieve then perhaps we can be of better help.

However, **assuming** you're trying to assign default keyword arguments using a `dict` then one way to achieve this would be to use [decorators](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808). For example:

```
def defaultArgs(default_kw):
    "decorator to assign default kwargs"
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(**kwargs):
            kw = {}
            kw.update(default_kw)  # apply defaults
            kw.update(kwargs)  # apply from input args
            f(**kw)  # run actual function with updated kwargs
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap
```

You can then use this decorator to assign default keyword arguments to a function that expects only keyword arguments:

```
defaults = {'foo':0, 'bar':1, 'baz':2}

@defaultArgs(defaults)
def func(**kwargs):
    print kwargs  # args accessible via the kwargs dict
```

Results:

```
func()  # prints {'baz': 2, 'foo': 0, 'bar': 1}
func(foo=2)  # prints {'baz': 2, 'foo': 2, 'bar': 1}

params = {'bar':1000, 'hello':'world'}
func(**params)  # prints {'baz': 2, 'foo': 0, 'bar': 1000, 'hello': 'world'}
```

Note that you will not be able to use positional arguments:

```
func(1, 2, 3)   # raises TypeError
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me accomplish what I want to do. I think it was, as you've stated, an XY problem; I was simply going about things the wrong way. It honestly kind of surprised me that I put myself into this predicament, since the last time I remember something like this happening was when I was a beginner at programming and learning Java for the first time, then being incensed that there wasn't a goto statement (when there were other, better solutions to my problem).

Comment: Glad you found a solution! We've all been in that position and sometimes all it takes is a gentle reminder to take a step back and reformulate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what you want i believe is `eval()` [link](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)

an answer i gave on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11865190/1561176

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you plan on accomplishing here.  The following works (sort of):

```
def func(**dct):
    pass

dct = {'foo':0, 'bar':1, 'baz':2}
func(**dct)
```

How do you plan on using `foo`, `bar` or `baz` in the function if they're created dynamically?  If you give some more details on what you're actually trying to accomplish, we might be able to be a little more helpful.