# Dynamic function signature in help()

Tags: python, adapter

I am building a library that automatically discovers remote API endpoints and populates an object with methods corresponding to the inferred endpoints. The dynamically created methods have the following structure:

```py
def proxy(*args, **kwds):
    # 1. Validate arguments: Do arguments match remote API?
    # 2. Forward call to remote API
    # 3. Parse and return response
    pass
```

This works so far. However, I would like to set the method signature shown with `help(proxy)` dynamically. It would increase the user interface greatly if users can see the inferred signatures directly and also use tab-completion for keyword arguments. Is there a way to decorate, annotate, or otherwise manipulate the function to achieve this?

The difference to [Dynamically define functions with varying signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954037/dynamically-define-functions-with-varying-signature) is that I only what to change the signature from the caller perspective. The definition of the method should be with `*args` and `**kwds`.

Comment: Would it work to dynamically define a wrapper function with the desired signature?

Comment: Sure wrapping the function would be fine but how do you define the wrapper?

Comment: I was thinking maybe one could define the wrapper as in the linked SO question using `eval`, but I haven't really thought it through.

Comment: Another idea would be to somehow use or mimic `@typing.overload` dynamically but neither can I tell you how this might work concretely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poking around the source of the `inspect` module, I realized that the information in `__signature__` is honored. Therefore, one can create a new, more informative signature dynamically as follows

```py
from inspect import Signature, Parameter

def proxy(*args, **kwds):
    pass

user_param = Parameter("user", kind=Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)
comment_param = Parameter("comment", kind=Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)
sig = Signature([user_param, comment_param])

proxy.__signature__ = sig 
proxy.__doc__ = "Post a new comment as given user"
proxy.__name__ = "post_comment"
```

Calling `help(proxy)` will show

```
post_comment(user, comment)
    Post a new comment as given user
```

and tab-completion suggests `user=` or `comment=`.

Please note, that the new signature is not enforced. Calling `proxy(no_such_argument="hello")` will not raise a `TypeError`, so the validation of the signature still needs to take place inside the proxy function.